# what is the alternative for deprecated android Material chip.setCloseIconEnabled(true)

Tags: android, material-design, android-chips

I am using material android chip. Here the close icon is not visible. After viewing some reference I m using **chip.setCloseIconEnabled(true)** but it is deprecated.

```
final Chip chip=new Chip(MainActivity.this);
        chip.setText(color);
        chip.setCheckable(false);
        chip.setClickable(true);
        chip.setCloseIconEnabled(true);
        chipGroup.addView(chip);
```

Comment: hmmm it's directly stated in the documentation

Comment: will you send me the link pls @Selvin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use `setCloseIconVisible(true)`

Comment: yes you are right. **setCloseIconEnabled(true)**  is deprecated instead we use setCloseIconVisible(true). That works thank you.